# Conditional Attributes - Asp.Net MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to add conditional disabled & class attributes to a dropdown form element. I have the following however it does not write out either of the attributes in any state. Is there a way around this.

```
<%=  Html.DropDownList("--Choose Make--", "models", ViewData["model_disabled"] == "false" ? new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "test" } : null)%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
ViewData["model_disabled"] == "false"
```

The return from ViewData[] is object. Calling == with two objects compares their identity (i.e., are they the exact same object instance), not their equality (i.e., are the strings the same value).

You can try this instead:

```
((string)ViewData["model_disabled"]) == "false"
```

**Edit:**

A slightly cleaner syntax is available with the [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MvcContrib) ViewData extensions:

```
ViewData.Get<string>("model_disabled") == "false"
```

Although this feels a little cleaner, you'll also notice it's slightly longer. :-p

Comment: Cheers Brad, is this the best way? Not sure I really like the readability of it at all.

Comment: I ran into something similar today, and discovered yet another syntax: *false.Equals(ViewData["model_disabled"])*. Although the syntax may seem a little odd at first, it also is concise and you get "automatic" null-checking without having to resort to things like encoding your boolean into strings or using frameworks. Cheers.